# Looping and comparing objects

Tags: php, arrays, object, loops

I have two arrays of objects,

They are identical except one has more items,

so they would look like

```
Array [arrayA]
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => interest 1
            [description] => interest one
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => interest 3
            [description] => interest three
        )

)



Array [arrayB]
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => all
            [description] => everything
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => interest 1
            [description] => interest one
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => interest 3
            [description] => interest three
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 5
            [name] => interest 4
            [description] => interest four
        )

)
```

Now what I want to do is, loop over `arrayB`, if the object is found in `arrayA` (maybe compare the ID?) then set `[checked] => true` else set `[checked] = false` on `arrayB`.

What is the easiest way to do this?

I have thought of doing maybe

```
foreach($arrayB as &$obj){
    $obj->checked = false;
    foreach($arrayA as $obja){
        if($obja->id == $obj->id){
            $obj->checked = true;
            break;
        }
        if($obja->id > $obj->id) //thanks to De3pTh0ught
            break;
    }
}
```

But there has to be a more efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a check to cut useless iterations. If you know that the object IDs in your arrays will always be in increasing order, you could include the condition: if $obja's ID is greater than $obj's ID, then `break` $arrayA's foreach loop, because that means that $obj will never find a match.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with this **horrible** hack (in 2 lines!):

```
$p = print_r($arrayA, true);
foreach($arrayB as &$o) $o->checked =substr_count($p, "[id] => {$o->id}\n") == 1;
```

Comment: Care to explain this? (although I don't think I would ever use this in production.. waaay to hard to understand...)

Comment: In line 1 we get a string just like what you have in your question. In line 2 we iterate over ids in $arrayB and for each we compose a substring like `[id] => 1` and check if there are 2 instances of it in $p, we assign the result of this comparison to `$o->checked`

Answer (score 0):

After some thought about how inefficient `substr_count` could be - think of its internal implementation; it cannot be very efficient - I came up with a slightly different method:

```
$b = print_r($arrayA, true);
foreach($arrayB as &$o) 
     $o->checked = strpos($b, "[id] => {$o->id}" . PHP_EOL, 60) !== false;
```